# Acceptable Reduce() amounts for google maps zoom levels?

Tags: google-maps, sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server Spatial to return large polygons to Google Maps for display.  Given that google maps has a zoom scale of 1 - 20, I would like to reduce my polygons (reduce function uses the Douglas Peucker formula) appropriately for the zoom level being displayed.  Does anyone have a table of visually acceptable levels of reduction per zoom level, or have a formula that would work well?